# Error passing setState value while submitting form: Error as "Unexpected template string expression no-template-curly-in-string"

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am a beginner at React.js so I am getting error as below. setState is not passing while submitting the form. Any solution here????

```
> class  Home extends Component{ constructor(props){
    >     super(props)
    >     this.state = {
    >         username:'',
    >         email:'',
    >         message:''
    >     } }
    > 
    > handleUsernameChange = (event) => { //event as parameter to capture
    > value
    >     this.setState({
    >         username: event.target.value
    >     }) } handleEmailChange = (event) => { //event as parameter to capture value
    >     this.setState({
    >         email: event.target.value
    >     }) } handleMessageChange = (event) => { //event as parameter to capture value
    >     this.setState({
    >         message: event.target.value
    >     }) }
    > 
    > handleSubmit = (event) =>{
    >     alert('${this.state.username} ${this.state.email} ${this.state.message}')
    >     event.preventDefault() }
```

[image]

Comment: Please bear in mind the significant difference between errors and warnings

Answer (score 0):

You would have to probably replace *quotes* `'` with a backticks `.

```
alert(`${this.state.username} ${this.state.email} ${this.state.message}`);
```